# Vue - Is it fine to store a value in session storage rigth from the main.js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, session-storage

So I have a session storage value set to false that I need to keep track of for the user session that is managed by Vuex. I set up the value right from the main.js file as such:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import axios from 'axios';
import store from './store'

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
sessionStorage.setItem('session', false);

App.prototype.$http = axios
```

And I was wondering whether it was ok to do it as such right from main.js file or if vuzI should do it elsewhere, such as in App.vue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's ok,the code runs well, you can use `sessionStorage.setItem` anywhere,because this is a synchronous method. if it goes badly, there must be something wrong with the logic of the code, i need more clues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Dontshowplease. Everything goes well, I was just wondering whether that could be an issue later in the process